# Heroku webpack deploy error when including image-webpack-loader

Tags: heroku, webpack

Getting the below error on heroku deploy after adding image-webpack-loader. Not sure how to resolve. Builds and runs fine locally.

```
 ⚠ The `/tmp/build_1f54e4cf69bc69296ee7e91d849e93d7/app/node_modules/mozjpeg/vendor/cjpeg` binary doesn't seem to work correctly
  ⚠ mozjpeg pre-build test failed
  ℹ compiling from source
  ✖ Error: autoreconf -fiv && ./configure --disable-shared --disable-dependency-tracking --with-jpeg8  --prefix="/tmp/build_1f54e4cf69bc69296ee7e91d849e93d7/app/node_modules/mozjpeg/vendor" --bindir="/tmp/build_1f54e4cf69bc69296ee7e91d849e93d7/app/node_modules/mozjpeg/vendor" --libdir="/tmp/build_1f54e4cf69bc69296ee7e91d849e93d7/app/node_modules/mozjpeg/vendor" && make -j2 && make install -j2
Command failed: ./configure --disable-shared --disable-dependency-tracking --with-jpeg8  --prefix="/tmp/build_1f54e4cf69bc69296ee7e91d849e93d7/app/node_modules/mozjpeg/vendor" --bindir="/tmp/build_1f54e4cf69bc69296ee7e91d849e93d7/app/node_modules/mozjpeg/vendor" --libdir="/tmp/build_1f54e4cf69bc69296ee7e91d849e93d7/app/node_modules/mozjpeg/vendor"
configure: error: no nasm (Netwide Assembler) found
    at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:275:12)
    at emitTwo (events.js:126:13)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:214:7)
    at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:925:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:209:5)

       > optipng-bin@3.1.4 postinstall /tmp/build_1f54e4cf69bc69296ee7e91d849e93d7/app/node_modules/optipng-bin
       > node lib/install.js
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The heroku server didn't have nasm support, which image-webpack-loader needed to get all the binaries for mozjpeg. By adding the Apt-buildpack found here https://elements.heroku.com/buildpacks/heroku/heroku-buildpack-apt#buildpack-instructions and adding a file named Aptfile with nasm to the root of my project, the heroku server is now able to complete the image-webpack-loader build successfully.